# Undefined reference to `pthread_create'- Replit c++

Tags: c++, replit

I am having a problem in replit. I know how to and have made threads before in other compilers like VS 2019. But for some reason in replit I am not able to create a new thread.

My current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <pthread>

void waveThreader()
{
std::cout<<"Hello!";
}

int main()
{
std::cout<<"Start!";
std::thread thread1(waveThreader);
thread1.join();
return 0;
}
```

I tried using:

```
pthread_t thread1;
pthread_create(&wvy, NULL, waveThreader, NULL);

void * waveThreader(void *arguments)
{
  std::cout<<"Hello!";
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Why not use std::thread or std::async? They've been part of C++ since C++11. Work like a charm in combination with lambda functions.

Comment: @PepijnKramer ya I am currently using std::thread. but I always get an Undefined reference to `pthread_create' error...

Comment: yes that can still used under the hood ...  I don't know replit, seems to support C++11. Maybe a configuration or a setting error I don't know